# Setting Proper Header for Caching in PHP

Tags: php, caching, http-headers, readfile

I'm using php to output an image using `readfile` function. I've set the headers for this php file as below:

```
$expires = 60*60*7;
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + $expires));
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
```

Both `expire` and `Cache-Control` headers are set, but each time i load the url, image gets downloaded. Is there any other header rule needed to enable caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Content Disposition header:

`header("Content-Disposition: inline;filename=something.jpg")`

This tells the browser to display it inline (rather than the default attchment, which triggers the download). Attachments will download regardless of cache values.